# Unable to push fetched data to global array insise a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, scope, global-variables

I have a problem in manipulating a global array.

The code works well if it written like this

```js
  function getChatBox(originMessage) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(
        Message.aggregate([
          {
            $match: { _id: originMessage }
          },
          {
            $unwind: "$subMessages"
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "messages",
              localField: "subMessages",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "chained"
            }
          },
          {
            $unwind: "$chained"
          },
          {
            $project: { chained: 1, _id: 0 }
          }
        ])
      );
    });
  }

  let chatBoxes = [];
  if (user.messages.length > 0) {
    user.messages.forEach(async msg => {
      //let chatBox = await getChatBox(msg.originMessage);
      //chatBoxes.push(chatBox);
      //chatBoxes.push(await getChatBox(msg.originMessage));
      chatBoxes.push("cool");
      console.log(chatBoxes);
    });
  }
  console.log("outer", chatBoxes);
```

[And the output is like this when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ4lJ.png)

However once I add a line of code (for fetching data from the database) the global array dose not change.

between ** ** is the line of code added (let chatBox = await getChatBox(msg.originMessage);):

```js
      function getChatBox(originMessage) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve(
            Message.aggregate([
              {
                $match: { _id: originMessage }
              },
              {
                $unwind: "$subMessages"
              },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "messages",
                  localField: "subMessages",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "chained"
                }
              },
              {
                $unwind: "$chained"
              },
              {
                $project: { chained: 1, _id: 0 }
              }
            ])
          );
        });
      }

      let chatBoxes = [];
      if (user.messages.length > 0) {
       user.messages.forEach(async msg => {
          **let chatBox = await getChatBox(msg.originMessage);**
          //chatBoxes.push(chatBox);
          //chatBoxes.push(await getChatBox(msg.originMessage));
          chatBoxes.push("cool");
          console.log(chatBoxes);
        });
      }
      console.log("outer", chatBoxes);
```

And the output shows this:
[I don't know why the order of the logs changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw1cM.png)

Please help me understand what is going on.
I want to push into the global array (chatBoxes) the fetched data but outside of the function the array is still empty (not empty if I add in the function a simple string).

I suspect that the code after the forEach runs before it ends looping. Maybe this is the problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable chatBox is declared with `let` statement, then chekBox would be available just into its scope (the anonymous function inside `user.message.forEach()`.

Change `let` with `var` statement, and if checkBox is a global variable it would be better to declare it outside `forEach()` scope, maybe at the top of the `function getChatBox()`

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. I changed it to var. the chatBoxes is already outside of the forEach. When the fetching happens somehow the global variable changes only inside the forEach and then outside of it the value of the array is same as it was initiated. Also it changes the logs order, It skips the code inside the forEach and then it runs it.

Comment: Tha's because you redeclare checkBox with "let checkBox" inside forEach(), it's a matter of pointer (invisible to programmer with javascript).
I think will work if you cut off the "let" statement inside forEach()

Comment: I changed it but it dose not work :( The chatBox variable is the single item I want to push to the chatBoxes array.

Comment: Can you share the data represented by originMessage, in order to prove your code clearly? Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Sure, originMessage is an id of message documents in mongoDB (for example: ObjectId("5bd33cce32b3e62d1450aa12")). Origin messages are the first messages sent. every response message to the origin message has it's originMessage ID in its document.

Comment: I created a sort of your user object, but the code works only if I put away the keyword "await" before getChatBox(msg.originMessage). It's weird. By the way without await "chatBox (result of getChatBox()) is a promises object, but empty {}...
Do you have the same error?

Comment: What's "Message.aggregate( )"? Maybe would be better if you give me, at least, one of the value returned from Message.aggregate( ), because the goal of this thread is not Message.aggregate. Anyway we are close

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I'm not sure how yet. I user a regular for loop instead the forEach. appernatly using async/await inside of forEach does not work well. I'm learning about it. Read here for more: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404